# Things to be considered - HNSC Url is getting changed in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: navigation, url

We are about the change the Url of the HNSC in SharePoint 2010? I could see the below topics to be taken care of

1. Search Service - Indexing.
2. Excel trusted locations.
3. Mysite Host Url - Yes, once again HNSC based.
4. Admin Scripts
5. Hard coded Urls in Navigations, documentations, workflows & Content Editor webparts.
6. SSL Accelerators / Load Balancers updates.

however this there an easy way to handle - Point#5?

Especially, How could I quickly find the hard coded Urls(absolute URLs) in the Navigations & on the Content Editor webparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think so you can do this without any kind of development. But I saw this free tool from Codeplex which will find and replace the hardcoded urls.

> SharePoint Search and Replace replaces hardcoded strings in SharePoint
>   lists, document libraries, web part properties and text-based
>   documents.

[SharePoint Find and Replace](http://spfnr.codeplex.com/)

Also check this blog, he is talking about how to change the abosulte url to relatives...may be help ful for you.

[Updating SharePoint Absolute URLs With Relative URLs Using Windows PowerShell](http://sharepointquester.com/2012/10/30/updating-sharepoint-absolute-urls-with-relative-urls-using-windows-powershell/)